# How make main screen to fade?

Tags: android, fade

I have main screen call by command ("   setContentView(R.layout.main); ") and I have SlidingDrawer delow. Now, when I open SlidingDrawer I what main screen to go hard fade, because SlidingDrawer doesn`t have background and then visibility is bad.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's [a link](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/splash-fade-activity-animations-overridependingtransition-t9464.html) of fade tutorial for android ;)